# What determines where a sqlite3 database file will be stored when creating it from the command line utility?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Recently I was reading that when launching mac Terminal and typing in this:

```
sqlite3 mydatabase.db
```

it will create a mydatabase.db file on disk. But where?

Answer (score 2):

In your current directory. Use `pwd` to determine it if you don't know it.

UPDATE:

Regarding the 'current' directory: If you launch an terminal there will be a directory which will be used as context for all commands (like sqlite3) you execute. This directory is called the *current* or *working* directory. On startup of the terminal it is usually your home direcory. You can always retrieve it with the command `pwd` (*p*rint *w*orking *d*irectory) or change it with the `cd` command.

Comment: what does "current" mean? there, where finder currently points to?